# DataCloneError: An object could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I need to pass a Hash function by using the javascript postMessage. I'm using the browser Firefox. When I'm sending this I'm getting the below exception.
'DataCloneError: An object could not be cloned' The code which I have implemented so far is as below.

```
    var mes = CryptoJS.SHA256(clientId + origin + sessionState);
    opIFrame.postMessage(mes,endPoint);
```

When I'm sending a string value this works successfully. I tried to send mes.toString() but it still gives the same error. I saw several threads on this topic. But could not configure a solution. Please advice me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the mes variable contains a WordArray object after the call to CryptoJS.SHA256 by logging it into the console. It looks like the object you're trying to send via postMessage() is not what you're expecting (possibly an Error or a Function object).